# Contacting Pulse Audio over Dbus

Tags: dbus, pulseaudio

I am trying to write a basic volume application. Since I'm writing this in Ruby I don't want to extend the C library or use `ffi`, instead I trying to write this with `ruby-dbus` I got the `Address` Property with `/org/pulse_audio/server_lookup1` but the file the address points to doesn't exist. Is Pulse Audio properly configured for `dbus`?

Answer (score 10):

Ubuntu ships Pulse Audio without D-Bus support. To enable it put the following line at the end of file `/etc/pulse/default.pa`:

```
load-module module-dbus-protocol
```

Restart Pulse Audio:

```
pkill pulseaudio; pulseaudio
```

[Solution](https://github.com/mk-fg/pulseaudio-mixer-cli/issues/1#issuecomment-8169296) found at [pulseaudio-mixer-cli](https://github.com/mk-fg/pulseaudio-mixer-cli) project which demonstrates how to use pulseaudio over D-Bus.

Comment: I you want to make the configuration on a per user level, the files is `$HOME/.config/pulse/default.pa`.

Comment: This is still valid after the upgrade to Ubuntu 20 for people wondering if they need it. I accepted the config file overwrites during the upgrade and had to re-add it, indicating they still don't ship with the dbus module loaded

Answer (score 1):

On my system (openSUSE 12.1), PA does point to an existing socket. This code 
([gist](https://gist.github.com/4111846))

```
#! /usr/bin/env ruby
require 'rubygems'
require 'dbus'
b = DBus.session_bus
ps = b.service 'org.PulseAudio1'
po = ps.object '/org/pulseaudio/server_lookup1'
po.introspect
pi = po['org.PulseAudio.ServerLookup1']
a = pi['Address']
path = a.split('=').last
system 'stat', path
```

produces

```
$ ruby ~/snippets/dbus-pulseaudio.rb 
  File: `/home/mvidner/.pulse/7c5e87305bb28b5a0661f8180000054c-runtime/dbus-socket'
  Size: 0               Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   socket
Device: 801h/2049d      Inode: 1332590     Links: 1
Access: (0777/srwxrwxrwx)  Uid: (11018/ mvidner)   Gid: (  100/   users)
Access: 2012-11-19 09:07:20.566053943 +0100
Modify: 2012-11-19 09:07:20.566053943 +0100
Change: 2012-11-19 09:07:20.566053943 +0100
 Birth: -
```